# Parsing paginated JSON Response from an API weird behaviour

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I am trying to extract some data from an API that seems to give paginated JSON response.

I decided to make a list where each JSON will be an element and then try to make 1 dataframe out of it.

```
def get_json_list():

    url_address = "https://api.some.api"
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Token token=mytoken',
    }

    # results will be appended to this list
    all_time_entries = []

    # loop through all pages and return JSON object
    for page in range(1, 3):
        params = {'start_date': '2020-01-01',
                  'end_date': '2020-06-12',
                  "page[size]": '2',
                  "page[number]": page
                  }
        response = requests.get(url="https://api.some.api", headers=headers,params=params).json()
        all_time_entries.append(response)
        page += 1


    data = json.dumps(all_time_entries, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

    return data
```

I've checked and this gives me valid JSON strings in the list, but when I tried to get the first one like this below it seems it has assigned nothing and it prints nothing as well.

```
data_arr = get_json_list()
for i in data_arr:
    print(data_arr[1])
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `json.dumps()` returns string

Comment: oh, I am a silly goose it seems.  Thank you.